# Как правильно изменить цикл, чтобы получить нужный формат данных в словаре

Tags: python, циклы, словари

Есть цикл

```
basic_dict = {}
for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
    basic_dict[city.text.lstrip()] = {}
    for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
        name = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
        detailed_url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
        basic_dict[city.text.lstrip()][name] = dict(url=detailed_url)
return basic_dict
```

Сейчас результат возвращается в виде словаря следующего формата

```
{
 city:
    {name:{url:detailed_url},
     name:{url:detailed_url}},
 city:
     {name:{url:detailed_url},
     {name:{url:detailed_url},
     {name:{url:detailed_url}}
}
```

Как переделать цикл, чтобы формат был

```
{
city:{name:{url:detailed_url}},
city:{name:{url:detailed_url}},
city:{name:{url:detailed_url}},
city:{name:{url:detailed_url}},
city:{name:{url:detailed_url}}
}
```

?

Comment: Вы, получается, хотите вернуть список словарей?

Comment: В вашем первом примере возврата не совпадает количество фигурных скобок

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, к-во скобок поправил. Да, мне нужен список словарей. Я хочу, чтобы каждая строка записывалась в файл новой строкой и чтобы в ней был указан город (т.е. чтобы в каждой строке были все данные для каждого name). Пробовал разными способами засунуть город перед "{name:{url:detailed_url}}", никак не получается. Сформировать {name:{url:detailed_url}} получается, но как только добавляю city, получаю кучу дублей.

Comment: Поправка. Не список словарей, а 1 словарь, просто в нужном формате (чтоб в каждой строке было city)

Comment: У вас в словаре ключи повторяются. В словаре (dict) не могут ключи повторяться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре ключи (city) не могут повторяться.

Есть варианты как сделать вашу запись в файл:

Вариант 1. Оставить первый вариант со словарями как есть, но при записи в файл сделать двойной цикл: внешний по ключам словаря (city), внутренний по вложенным записям (name).

```
for city in basic_dict:
    list = basic_dict[city]
    for item in list:
        //Тут писать в файл: key, item
```

Вариант 2. Избавиться от словаря и перейти к массиву классов.

```
class MyClass:
    city = ""
    cinema = ""
    url = ""

 basic_list = []
 for city in tree.xpath(".//div[@class='city-caption']"):
     city_text = city.text.lstrip()
     for cinema in city.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]/li/a"):
         item = MyClass()
         item.city = city_text
         item.cinema = cinema.xpath("text()")[0]
         item.url = cinema.xpath("@href")[0]
         basic_list.append(item)
```